# How to match only documents where a condition, that includes another array, applies to all documents in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There are a lot of questions/answers sounding exactly like what I'm looking for but I couldn't find a single one that actually worked for me.

Sample data:

```
{
  "_id": "5daeb61790183fd4d4361d6c",
  "orderMessageId": "7563_21",
  "orderId": "OS00154",
  "orderEntryDate": "2019-06-17T00:00:00.000Z",
  "typeOfOrder": "ORD",
  "express": false,
  "name1": "xxx",
  "name2": "xxx",
  "name3": " ",
  "contact": "IN KOMMISSION",
  "street": "xxx",
  "city": "xxx",
  "zipcode": "1235",
  "country": "xx",
  "customerId": "51515",
  "lnatMarketCode": "Corporate - Regulatory",
  "shipmentCarrier": "ABH",
  "typeOfShipment": "83",
  "typeOfShipmentDescr": "xxx",
  "orderTextfield": " ",
  "orderTextfield02": " ",
  "text2": " ",
  "LinVw": [
    {
      "orderLineMessageId": "OS05451",
      "orderLineId": 5,
      "articleId": "19200",
      "articleDescription": "xxx",
      "productId": "OS1902",
      "productDescription": "xxx",
      "baseQuantityUnit": "EA",
      "quantityOrdered": 2,
      "isbn": "978357468",
      "issn": " ",
      "orderSubmissionDate": "2019-06-06T00:00:00.000Z",
      "customerPurchaseOrderId": "728188175",
      "lnatCustomerIdAtSupplier": " ",
      "supplierDeliveryNoteId": " ",
      "fulfillmentContactName": "xxxx",
      "customerVatRegistrationCode": "AT4151511900",
      "listPriceInclVat": 21.4955,
      "text": " ",
      "orderResponses": [
        {
          "orderMessageId": "7718677_1",
          "orderLineMessageId": "OS0000015451",
          "orderId": "OS000154",
          "orderLineId": 5,
          "articleId": "1911200",
          "quantity": 2,
          "quantityNotShipped": 0,
          "reasonForNotShippedCode": null,
          "reasonForNotShipped": null,
          "shipmentDate": "2019-10-04T00:00:00.000Z",
          "deliveryNoteId": null,
          "trackingIds": [
            {
              "trackingId": null,
              "quantityRefToTracking": "2",
              "weightRefToTracking": "0.0"
            }
          ],
          "type": "orderresponse",
          "filepath": "xxxORDERRESP_20191004131209.xml",
          "_id": "OS005451"
        },
        {
          "orderMessageId": "753_21",
          "orderLineMessageId": "OS015451",
          "orderId": "O00154",
          "orderLineId": 5,
          "articleId": "100200",
          "quantity": 0,
          "quantityNotShipped": 2,
          "reasonForNotShippedCode": "01",
          "reasonForNotShipped": "Out of Stock",
          "shipmentDate": null,
          "deliveryNoteId": null,
          "trackingIds": [
            {
              "trackingId": null,
              "quantityRefToTracking": "0",
              "weightRefToTracking": "0.0"
            }
          ],
          "type": "orderresponse",
          "filepath": "xxxxORDERRESP_20190618161529.xml",
          "_id": "OS0000015451"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "filepath": "xxxxxORDER_7539563_20190618_071522.xml"
}
```

I want to match all documents, where *all documents* in the array LinVw, match the following condition:

```
{'$or': [{'LinVw.orderResponses': {'$exists': False}}, {'LinVw.orderResponses.shipmentDate': {'$type': 10}}]}
```

To put it in words: I want to match documents, if the array LinVw.orderResponses doesn't exist, or it contains only documents, that don't have a valid shipmentDate.

Currently I have this (using pymongo):

```
result = order_collection.aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$LinVw"},
{"$match": {'$or': [{'LinVw.orderResponses': {'$exists': False}}, {'LinVw.orderResponses.shipmentDate': {'$type': 10}}]}}
])
```

But of course this doesn't consider that all documents inside LinVw.orderResponses should match the condition.

Most examples our there don't deal with this kind of nesting and I was unable to rewrite them accordingly.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: will you explain an objective little bit?

Comment: @niranjanharpale I'm sorry, I'm not following. What do you want me to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/index.html) stage.

Inside `$redact` stage, you write down the query matching documents which you want to ignore(having invalid shipMent date). That's it.

Comment: @pypat  I would have written the complete query for you but your sample document is not properly formatted(missing closing brackets). Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any difficulty implementing it. And please do upvote or accept answer if this answer helps you.

Comment: Thank you but I feel like I'm left with the same issue. At least the result is the same. Here's my redacted stage: {"$redact": {"$cond": [{"$not":[{'shipmentDate': None}]}, "$$PRUNE", "$$KEEP"]}}

Comment: @pypat I can assure you it can be done using $redact. It would be easier for me to answer if you can simply format your sample document and share the sample result as well. Make sure to test your sample document by inserting it db, if it doesn't give any error, I can write and test it on my system.

Comment: I did fix the python dict in my op, it is insertable now.

Comment: Nope. Too many erorrs 
`E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: False is not defined
E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: None is not defined`
and so on

Comment: I apologize, it was a valid python dict but not valid json. Should be proper now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201327/discussion-between-invider-and-pypat).

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it:

```
result = order_collection.aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$LinVw"},
{"$match": {'$or': [{'LinVw.orderResponses': {'$exists': False}}, {'LinVw.orderResponses.shipmentDate': {'$type': 10}}]}},
{"$match": {'LinVw.orderResponses.shipmentDate': {"$not":{'$type': 9}}}},
{"$project":{"_id":0, "LinVw.orderLineMessageId":1, "LinVw.orderResponses":1}}
])
```

Comment: @invider maybe you could verify that this makes sense ?